# What is sequence of servlet-container and dispatcher servlet for http request?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, servlets

What is sequence of servlet-container and dispatcher servlet for http request?
Is servlet container front of dispatcher servlet?
Some posts explain Dispatcher servlet is in Servlet container.
But I know Tomcat is kind of servlet container and dispatcher-servlet is Spring's feature. So it's wired.

Comment: The `DispatcherServlet` is, as you said, _in_ the servlet container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- *Dispatcher Servlet* is just a conventional name for the ordinary servlet. It's called "dispatcher" because it simply *dispatches* requests to the corresponding handler servlet objects. It is not Spring feature, rather, Spring uses it a lot for implementing its mechanisms.
- *Servlet Container* is the Web Container, which simply contains სervlets and manages their lifecycle. There are several Servlet Container implementations and of those implementations is found in the Apache Tomcat.
- *Tomcat* is not *kind of*, but it **has** a Servlet Container engine.

Dispatcher Servlet (like any other servlet) lives within the Servlet Container.